# How do I use delete button and up and down button from keyboard in an angular app

Tags: angular, keypress

I am trying to build a todo app
The app has a list of tasks to be done
these tasks can be deleted as well 
The app works fine with mouse clicks
how do i make the app respond to keypresses

I want the app to go down the list when arrowdown is pressed
and go up when arrow up is pressed

focus on the element as keys are pressed

once it is focused i must be able to press enter to mark task as done and press delete to delte task

app.html

```
<input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="What needs to be done" [(ngModel)]="todoTitle" (keyup.enter)="addTodo()">
<todo-item *ngFor="let todo of todoService.todosFiltered()" [todo]="todo">
 </todo-item>
```

todo-item.html

```
<div class="todo-item">
<div class="todo-item-left">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="todo.completed">
<div  class="todo-item-label" [ngClass]="{ 'completed' : todo.completed }"{{ todo.title }}</div>

</div>
<div class="remove-item" (click)="todoService.deleteTodo(todo.id)" >
&times;
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@HostListeners` to listen to keyboard events and utilize it as per your need.

```
@HostListener('window:keydown.arrowup', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:keydown.arrowdown', ['$event'])
```

You can refer the below project which uses arrow keys for navigation through the todo list,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2ejnaz

You can also read more about Angular HostListners at,
https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener

Answer (score 3):

In your *ngFor you can handle key down event with `(keydown.arrowup)=clickArrowup($event)` for arrow up and `(keydown.arrowdown)=clickArrowdown($event)` for event emitted when you'll press Arrow down button. In the same way you can handle event with enter button with `(keydown.enter)=clickEnter($event)` and delete with `(keydown.backspace)=clickBackspace($event)`.

In alternative you can pass a single function in your html template like so: `(keydown)=onKeydown($event)` and in your ts:

```
onKeydown(event) { 

if (event.key === "Enter") { console.log(event); }

if (event.key === "Backspace") { console.log(event); } 

if (event.key === "ArrowUp") { console.log(event); } 

if (event.key === "ArrowDown") { console.log(event); } 

}
```

Hope It can help.